# Are gourd leaves edible?

Tags: recipe-scaling, menu-planning

[image]

That is, the leaves of a gourd, I know a lot of menus include the fruit of the gourd, but not the leaves.

I am looking for a way to eat them, if possible maybe I can include in a dish or maybe a side dish? If not, can I eat it raw? Because this seems to be abundant here in the Philippines.

Comment: I'm sorry but we don't do recipe recommendations here. Please see the [help on-topic](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) pages for more info.

Comment: @Catija, oh sorry. How about if I changed the question to something like `is gorud leaves edible`?

Comment: That would be much better, I believe.

Comment: Done editing my question.

Answer (score 1):

At least [*some* cucurbit leaves are edible](https://www.google.com/search?q=squash&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=cucurbit%20leaves%20recipe), and [here](http://www.thekitchn.com/did-you-know-you-can-eat-pumpkin-leaves-tips-from-the-kitchn-207383).

[The genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucurbita) isn't known for producing toxins, but there *may* be a few wild cards in there.
Proceed with caution, if you proceed at all.
I'll stick with Habanero, Bell, and Jalapeno pepper leaves cooked in butter and lemon juice.

There are books with titles like "Edible Plants of the Tropics" or perhaps even "Edible Plants of the Philippines", that can probably tell you about your particular gourd, but you'll probably have to go to a college botanical library to find them.

Later, while cleaning out old files:
The book I was thinking of is called **Edible Leaves of the Tropics** by Martin, Ruberte and Metzner.
The third edition came out in 1998, so if your library doesn't have it, there are now [lots of places to buy it](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22edible%20leaves%20of%20the%20tropics%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Comment: What does pepper leaves have to do with gourd leaves?

Comment: @Catija Not much, other than it's another tropical genus which, having looked it up in "Edible Plants of the Tropics", I *know* the leaves of the common types are edible.

Comment: It's not even the same genus though. Gourds are in the same genus as melons and squash, not peppers. Whether true or no it's a confusing tidbit to add.